# Swift: Distance formatting

Tags: ios, swift

I need to convert distances in meters to kilometers.
For example I have the following array of meters:

[10, 100, 5000, 20000, 180000, 180500, 1800000]

Now I want to have these values in kilometers with minimum 3 digits overall. But only if the distance is smaller than 100 km.

[0,01 ; 0,10 ; 5,00 ; 20,0 ; 180 ; 180 ; 1800]

I have tried this with the NumberFormatter:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
```

Do I need therefor a IF/ELSE or can i achieve this with the normal NumberFormatter?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need two formatters but you should probably consider using `MKDistanceFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
let a = [10, 100, 5_000, 20_000, 180_000, 180_500, 1_800_000]

let maxIntegerDigits = Int(log(Float80(Int.max)) + 1)

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1

let result: [String] = a.map { distance in
    let inKilometers = Double(distance) / 1000
    if distance < 10_000 {
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 1
    }
    else if distance < 100_000 {
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 2
    } else {
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = maxIntegerDigits
    }
    return formatter.string(for: inKilometers) ?? ""
}

print(result)  //["0.01", "0.10", "5.00", "20.0", "180", "180", "1,800"]
```

You can set the locale of the number formatter in order to change the grouping and decimal separators.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `NumberFormatter` for this, you can create method which returns number of fraction digits which you want to have for your number

```
private func getNumberOfFractionDigits(for number: Double) -> Int {
    switch self {
    case ..<10:
        return 2
    case ..<100:
        return 1
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

then just set `maximumFractionDigits` property of formatter to result of `getFractionDigits` for your number divided by thousand

```
let dividedNumber = yourNumber / 1000
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = getNumberOfFractionDigits(for: dividedNumber)
let formatedNumber = Double(numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: dividedNumber))!)!
```